# Selectively add texture to dots using ggplot2

Tags: r

I have a data.frame (df1) like this:

> ```
>                 Size1    Size2 
>     Sample1     0.32     0.44
>     Sample2     0.12     0.12
>     Sample3     0.22     0.11
>     Sample4     0.16     0.54
>     Sample5     0.78     0.23
>     Sample6     0.22     0.81
>     Sample7     0.98     0.09
>      .....       ....     ...
> ```

where Sample* are row names
and an annotation data.frame (df2) that looks like this:

> ```
>                Annotation    
>     Sample1     Blood     
>     Sample2     Blood     
>     Sample3     Blood     
>     Sample4     BM     
>     Sample5     BM     
>     Sample6     PBMC     
>     Sample7     PBMC     
>      .....       ....
> ```

where Sample* are row names

To plot data I used the following code:

> ```
>   p = ggplot(df1, aes(df1[,1], df1[,2], label=rownames(df1))) +
>   geom_point(aes(color = factor(df2[,1])), size = 5)+ labs(color = "Color_Code") +
>   scale_colour_manual(guide = 'legend',name = 'Legend',
>                 labels = c("Blood", "BM", "PBMC"),                                 
>                 values = c("red", "blue", "green"))
> ```

Now, is there a way to add a texture (for example horizontal lines inside the dot) only to dots corresponding to BM?
Totally I have 3000 rows and BM are around 550 samples (rows).

Thank you in advance

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "texture". Could you mock up what you expect in paint/preview/GIMP?

Comment: I believe OP means text and not texture

Comment: I just edited the question to be more clear!

Comment: Should we assume that df1 and df2 have the same number of rows and are aligned? If not, it would help to join them first.

Comment: They match in the length and order!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps use a different shape?

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)
inner_join(df1 %>% rownames_to_column(),
           df2 %>% rownames_to_column()) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = Size1, y = Size2, label = rowname, color = Annotation, shape = Annotation == "BM")) +
  geom_point(size = 5)+ labs(color = "Color_Code", shape = "BM") +
  scale_colour_manual(guide = 'legend',name = 'Legend',
                      labels = c("Blood", "BM", "PBMC"),                                 
                      values = c("red", "blue", "green")) + 
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(16,13), 
                     labels = c("No","Yes"))
```

[image]

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Size1 = c(0.32, 0.12, 0.22, 0.16, 0.78, 0.22, 0.98), Size2 = c(0.44, 0.12, 0.11, 0.54, 0.23, 0.81, 0.09)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3", "Sample4", "Sample5", "Sample6", "Sample7"))
df2 <- structure(list(Annotation = c("Blood", "Blood", "Blood", "BM", "BM", "PBMC", "PBMC")), row.names = c("Sample1", "Sample2", "Sample3", "Sample4", "Sample5", "Sample6", "Sample7"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Yes, it is what I was looking for. Thank you very much. I was a little bit confused on how and where add the additional information on the shape/texture. Thank you again